# Unexpected result on CAST or CONVERT in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

```
SELECT CAST (330/60 AS FLOAT) AS result
```

or

```
SELECT CONVERT(FLOAT, 330/60) AS result
```

Actually I am expecting result as 5.5

But it is returning 5. **Why?**

And tell me any solution to get **result as 5.5**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `60.0` to force fixed-point types:

```
 SELECT CAST (330/60.0 AS FLOAT) AS result
 SELECT CONVERT(FLOAT, 330/60.0) AS result
```

The calculation of `330/60` is done as integers which will round the result. After that you cast to float. You can use a numeric type right from the beginnging and don't need to cast:

```
SELECT 330/60.0 AS result
```

Comment: **Why** SELECT CONVERT(FLOAT, 330/60) AS result is giving  result **5**

Comment: Because **first** `330/60` is evaluated. **After that** is will be converted to float. And integers can't have floating point results.

Comment: `60.0` is `numeric(3,1)` datatype rather than `float`. `6E1` would be `float`

Comment: @MartinSmith: Thanks for the hint. Changed it in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of casting the answer to float ,you should try casting the denominator to float and then do the division

```
 Select 330/CAST(60 as float) as result
```

or else change the denominator to include decimal part as suggested by juergen d

```
 SELECT CAST (330/60.0 AS FLOAT) AS result
```